# Wrong site name when searching

Tags: search

I have a site called "Gethis", but every time I search for "Gethis" it gives me results of "Get his". It only gives me the right results if I search for the URL: `http://gethisweb.com/`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will take time and enough incoming links with *gethis* as the anchor text to get Google to assume people want *gethis* instead of a mistype on the phrase *get his*. Google is making the assumption that users want *get his* when that phrase is typed and 99.9999% of the time it is correct.

In simple terms your site will have to gain popularity before it is recognized, but that can be an issue when your site is difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

Search on `"gethis"` including the quotes or use the Advanced Search like this:

[image: Google Search]

You will then get the results you are after:

[image: Search Results]

Comment: But other people won't if they don't do an advanced search.

Comment: True! I wonder what percentage of searchers are familiar with advanced search or know to use inverted commas when searching for exact words and phrases?